# Flex container and text don't shrink to fit screen width

Tags: html, css

I want to display the information given in the picture below[image: picture of application]

The only problem is that it won't shrink when I check for responsibility. The margin **only** on the right side goes away and the text flows off the page.
[image]

When I try the responsive developer tools for an Iphone X it looks weird like this:
[image]

I am out of ideas on what to do.
Here is my HTML and CSS (I use angular for variable names, so if you want to replicate just put random text in):

CSS:

```css
    .mainContainer{
        margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

    .maskDetails {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
  
    .detail {
        flex: 50%;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .taskSelect{
        display: flex;
        column-gap: 10px;
    }

    .taskDescription{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .description{
        font-size: medium;
    }

    h4{
        font-size: medium;
    }

    .descriptionT{
        font-size: medium;
    }

    .detail:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #eeee;
    }
```

HTML:

```html
 <div class="mainContainer">

  <div class="maskSelect">
    <div>
      <h4>Maske:</h4>
    </div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" matTooltip="Bitte die Maske angeben, welche beim Arbeiten getragen wird.">
      <mat-label>Maske</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControl]="maskControl" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let mask of masks" [value]="mask">
          {{mask.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="maskControl.hasError('required')">Bitte Maskenart auswählen.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="maskDetails" *ngIf="!(mask.name==''||mask.name=='---')">
    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Name:</h4>
      <p>{{mask.name}}</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Beschreibung:</h4>
      <p>{{mask.bemerkung}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Schutzniveau:</h4>
      <p>{{mask.schutzniveau}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Gebrauchsdauer [min]:</h4>
      <p>{{mask.gebDauer}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Erholungsdauer [min]:</h4>
      <p>{{mask.erhoDauer}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Gebrauchsdauer/Schicht [min]:</h4>
      <p>{{mask.proSchicht}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>AMR Gruppe:</h4>
      <p>{{mask.amr}}</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
<div class="taskContainer">
  <div class="taskSelect">
    <div class="group" matTooltip="Bitte wählen Sie hier Ihren groben Tätigkeitsbereich aus.">
      <h4>Tätigkeitsbereich:</h4>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Tätigkeitsbereich</mat-label>
        <mat-select [formControl]="taskControl" required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let g of groups.group" [value]="g">
            {{g.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-error *ngIf="taskControl.hasError('required')">Bitte einen Bereich auswählen.</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="task"
      matTooltip="Bitte spezifische Tätigkeit auswählen. Lesen Sie sich bitte hierfür die Beschreibung durch.">
      <h4>Tätigkeit:</h4>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Tätigkeit</mat-label>
        <mat-select [formControl]="tControl" required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let t of task" [value]="t">
            {{t.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-error *ngIf="taskControl.hasError('required')">Bitte mindestens eine Tätigkeit auswählen.</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%;" *ngIf="!(t.name==''||t.name==' ')">
  <table class="taskDescription">
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
      <td class="description">
        Bezeichnung:
      </td>
      <td class="descriptionT">
        {{t.name}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
      <td class="description">
        Beschreibung:
      </td>
      <td class="descriptionT">
        {{t.beschreibung}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
      <td class="description">
        Faktor Arbeitsschwere:
      </td>
      <td class="descriptionT">
        {{t.arbeitsschwere}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div *ngIf="ergebnis.gebrauch!=0">
  <h2>Errechnete Gebrauchsdauer: {{ergebnis.gebrauch}} min bis zur Erholung.</h2>
  <h2>Errechnete Gebrauchsdauer/Schicht: {{ergebnis.schicht}} min.</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `gap` is not css property, is used in `display: grid;` and frameworks such as tailwind and bootstrap

Comment: @Sarout I forgot to delete it when I tried different things, doesn't make a difference though

Comment: I don't know if your question is unclear or I can't understand you, can you please describe what you exactly want?

Comment: `flex-wrap` and `align-items` are extra. they are defined for flex containers and not flex items. The text inside your elements is small enough. Can you more explain about: `The only problem is that it won't shrink when I check for responsibility. The margin only on the right side goes away and the text flows off the page. `

Comment: @Sarout The problem is, as seen in the picture, that the text and whole flex container is not shrinking when I shrink the page size. The text gets cut off and doesn't resize like it should inside a flex container. I want a consistent 10px margin on both left and right side. And the text should, of course, be inside the container and break accordingly.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi As seen in the pictures, when I shrink the page size horizontally, the content doesn't shrink with it, the size stays the same and gets cut off as a result of that.

Comment: I try that in firefox and it works fine. (text wraps). You use the from which browser?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Chrome, but I also use angular, and since I didn't think the code before and after would affect it, I didn't post the full html and css

Answer (score 1):

your code has no problems, is this what you want?

**EDIT** the `flex:50%;` is effextless. also `flex-wrap` and `align-items` not should placed for **`.detail`**

```css
.mainContainer {
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.maskDetails {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.detail {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.taskSelect {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.taskDescription {
  width: 100%;
}

.description {
  font-size: medium;
}

h4 {
  font-size: medium;
}

.descriptionT {
  font-size: medium;
}

.detail:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eeee;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">

  <div class="maskSelect">
    <div>
      <h4>Maske:</h4>
    </div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" matTooltip="Bitte die Maske angeben, welche beim Arbeiten getragen wird.">
      <mat-label>Maske</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControl]="maskControl" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let mask of masks" [value]="mask">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="maskControl.hasError('required')">Bitte Maskenart auswählen.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="maskDetails" *ngIf="!(mask.name==''||mask.name=='---')">
    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Name:</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Beschreibung:</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Schutzniveau:</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Gebrauchsdauer [min]:</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Erholungsdauer [min]:</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>Gebrauchsdauer/Schicht [min]:</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="detail">
      <h4>AMR Gruppe:</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="taskContainer">
    <div class="taskSelect">
      <div class="group" matTooltip="Bitte wählen Sie hier Ihren groben Tätigkeitsbereich aus.">
        <h4>Tätigkeitsbereich:</h4>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Tätigkeitsbereich</mat-label>
          <mat-select [formControl]="taskControl" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let g of groups.group" [value]="g">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error *ngIf="taskControl.hasError('required')">Bitte einen Bereich auswählen.</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="task" matTooltip="Bitte spezifische Tätigkeit auswählen. Lesen Sie sich bitte hierfür die Beschreibung durch.">
        <h4>Tätigkeit:</h4>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Tätigkeit</mat-label>
          <mat-select [formControl]="tControl" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let t of task" [value]="t">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error *ngIf="taskControl.hasError('required')">Bitte mindestens eine Tätigkeit auswählen.</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;" *ngIf="!(t.name==''||t.name==' ')">
    <table class="taskDescription">
      <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td class="description">
          Bezeichnung:
        </td>
        <td class="descriptionT">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.{{t.name}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td class="description">
          Beschreibung:
        </td>
        <td class="descriptionT">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td class="description">
          Faktor Arbeitsschwere:
        </td>
        <td class="descriptionT">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="ergebnis.gebrauch!=0">
    <h2>Errechnete Gebrauchsdauer: {{ergebnis.gebrauch}} min bis zur Erholung.</h2>
    <h2>Errechnete Gebrauchsdauer/Schicht: {{ergebnis.schicht}} min.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this code is correct for me too.

Comment: maybe, the issue is in Angular not in this code

Comment: That would be what I want but it still doesn't work with my app. I will edit my question to show my full Angular code.

Comment: @Sarout seem `flex:50%` is effextless. also `flex-wrap` and `align-items` not should placed for `.detail`.

Comment: @Sarout Thanks for your efforts. I attached a picture of how the chrome dev tools for a phone look. I am confused.

Comment: @sini.py your code has no problem, and this doesn't mean that you don't have an issue, please go to dev tools and check what's weird in the parents of this section and if you don't find anything send the styling of the parents in the devtools or host the website and don't worry, no need to confuse it's hard IK, you're welcome everytime